# Updating column in table based on multiple select values

Tags: sql, db2

Running a manual example in my IDE, I'm selecting an average based on a count and the sum of one of my columns like so:

```
SELECT
    sum(velocity)/count(*) as avg
from metrics
   where repnumber = 397
   and material = 1051
   and item = 1150
   and color = 99;
```

But I want to update the column `repvelocity` based on the above select.

So for every row, I want it to select the columns like above, and set `repvelocity` to the average

So I want:

```
material  |  item  |  color  |  velocity  |  repnumber  |  repvelocity
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               2       2           5           123          4.2
1               2       2           2           123          4.2
1               2       2           5           123          4.2
1               2       2           4           123          4.2
1               2       2           5           123          4.2

2               3       7           7           123          3.8
2               3       7           2           123          3.8
2               3       7           3           123          3.8
2               3       7           2           123          3.8
2               3       7           5           123          3.8
```

Basically, I have duplicate rows because the 'velocity' column is attributed to customers. So every where there is a combo of the repnumber, material, cover, color I want to update the repvelocity  to the average from above.

You can see it looked for every row that has material 1, item 2, color 2 and repnumber 123, did the count/sum average, and then updates the repvelocity for each row.

Is there a way I can do a whole-table update like this?

Comment: @gordon_linoff can you see my comment below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `join`:

```
update metrics m join
       (select repnumber, material, item, color, sum(m2.velocity)/count(*) as avg_velocity
        from metrics m2
        group by repnumber, material, item, color
       ) m2
       using (repnumber, material, item, color)
    set m.repvolocity = m2.avg_velocity;
```

I also wonder why you are using `sum(velocity)/count(*)`.  I would expect `avg(velocity)`.  The two are not *exactly* the same, but only differ if `velocity` is ever `NULL`.

In most other database, you would use a correlated subquery:

```
update metrics m
    set repvolocity = (select avg(m2.velocity)
                       from metrics m2
                       where m2.repnumber = m.repnumber and m2.material = m.material and m2.item = m.item and m2.color = m.color
                      );
```

Comment: So I should probably use avg(velocity) then?

Comment: @TomN. . . . Yes.  It is a slightly less work for the database and more directly shows your intent.

Comment: I just realized I totally flubbed and put mysql, but it's in db2 and this isn't wanting to run. WOuld the syntax be slightly different for this?

Answer (score -1):

Using the avg() function will be the best choice 
You can go for something like this if you do not want to use avg().

SELECT a.*,aa.repvelocity
  FROM     metrics a
       JOIN
           (  SELECT SUM (velocity) / COUNT (*) repvelocity, repnumber
                FROM metrics b
               WHERE     b.repnumber = 397
                     AND b.material = 1051
                     AND b.item = 1150
                     AND b.color = 99
            GROUP BY b.repnumber) aa
       ON aa.repnumber = a.repnumber;

I have just used repnumber to group and calculate.